# Google maps API only shows 3 markers out of 4?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, oop

I have this chunk of code and the multi marker set up should work correctly it's set up in an array and i loop over them, but the issue is i have 4 items in my array and it only gives me 3 out which seems strange to me because it should go through all of them.

```
    /*array for locations below */
var locations = [
  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Liverpool <br/><br/> 11th Floor, The Plaza<br/> 100 Old Hall Street <br/> Liverpool <br/> L3 9QJ <br/> <br/> 0151 242 1630</h4>', 53.4109146,-2.9947334999999384],

  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Manchester <br/><br/> Centurion House<br/>129 Deansgate<br/>Manchester<br/>M3 3WR <br/> <br/> 0161 393 9889  </h4>', 53.479798  -2.2479048],

  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment London <br><br> Warnford Court <br> 29 Throgmorton Street<br> London <br>  EC2N 2AT <br><br> 0203 817 7030</h4>', 51.5074, 0.1278],

  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Birmingham</h4>', 52.48208 -1.9027578],


  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Leeds <br><br> West One <br> Wellington Street<br>Leeds<br>LS1 1BA <br><br>0113 887 2170 </h4>', 53.8008 , -1.5491]
];

// Setup the different icons and shadows
var iconURLPrefix = 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/';

var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'marker_black.png',

]
var iconsLength = icons.length;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('MAPS'), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6369, -1.1398),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  scrollwheel:false,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControlOptions: {
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
});





var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxWidth: 160
});

var markers = new Array();

var iconCounter = 0;

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: icons[iconCounter]
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  iconCounter++;

  if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
    iconCounter = 0;
  }
}

function autoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
  }
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
autoCenter();
```

Comment: which one is not shown? the last one?

Comment: ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Birmingham</h4>', 52.48208 -1.9027578],

Comment: Your 2nd and 4th have both lat & lng in one string, separated by space. 1st and 3rd are two different values in array. And it shows 3/5

Comment: wowww something so simple thanks ;)

Comment: simple things always take the most amount of time. I don't know how i spotted that myself. :D accept my answer if you think I saved you some time.

Answer (score 1):

Your data array has errors. Second and fourth array has lat and lng as one value, although the rest are (correctly) two different values.
Add commas between those lat and lng coords and you should be fine.

```
var locations = [
  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Liverpool <br/><br/> 11th Floor, The Plaza<br/> 100 Old Hall Street <br/> Liverpool <br/> L3 9QJ <br/> <br/> 0151 242 1630</h4>', 53.4109146,-2.9947334999999384],

  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Manchester <br/><br/> Centurion House<br/>129 Deansgate<br/>Manchester<br/>M3 3WR <br/> <br/> 0161 393 9889  </h4>', 53.479798,  -2.2479048],

  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment London <br><br> Warnford Court <br> 29 Throgmorton Street<br> London <br>  EC2N 2AT <br><br> 0203 817 7030</h4>', 51.5074, 0.1278],

  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Birmingham</h4>', 52.48208, -1.9027578],


  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Leeds <br><br> West One <br> Wellington Street<br>Leeds<br>LS1 1BA <br><br>0113 887 2170 </h4>', 53.8008 , -1.5491]
];
```